# How to project an image on spherical surface with least possible distortion

Tags: image-processing

I did not know where to ask, I will try it here. I work in a local planetarium and I wonder if it is possible to edit an image in such way, that when projected on spherical cupola (diameter 8 m), it would not look too much distorted. Is there any easy way to edit an image this way?

Comment: Figure out how the image is mapped to the sphere (you can test with an image of a grid) and then work backwards

Comment: It doesn't sound dissimilar to the problem of coping with the distortions needed when rendering for VR glasses, e.g. barrel/pincushion
https://www.imgtec.com/blog/speeding-up-gpu-barrel-distortion-correction-in-mobile-vr/

Comment: Check out the projections used for maps (globe vs planar): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection
Then choose the one that preserves the properties that you want (area, angles...)